# Ubuntu 12.10 wireless trouble macbook pro

Tags: wireless, internet, mac, macbook-pro

I recently installed ubuntu 12.10 on my Macbook Pro mid 2012 alongside Mountain Lion using rEFIt boot. I am having trouble connecting to wireless network. When I click the internet icon at the top of the menu bar, no networks are shown and when I try to manually connect through edit connections, it doesen't work. I did not instal any drivers for anything, but the trackpad (even the two finger scrolling works) , brightness keys, volume keys and keyboard illumination led brightness works. So.. I am guessing it came with some drivers.

Here are my results of some things I typed into terminal

1. `nm-tool`

   ```
   State: disconnected

   Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------  
   Type:              Wired  
   Driver:            tg3
   State:             unavailable
   Default:           no
   HW Address:        A8:20:66:2A:05:23

   Capabilities:
   Carrier Detect:  yes

   Wired Properties
   Carrier:         off
   ```
2. `sudo lshw -C network`

   ```
   PCI (sysfs)  

   *-network               

   description: Ethernet interface

   product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe

   vendor: Broadcom Corporation

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0

   logical name: eth0

   version: 10

   serial: a8:20:66:2a:05:23

   capacity: 1Gbit/s

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 

   10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123 

   firmware=57765-v1.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair

   resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff

   *-network

   description: Network controller

   product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n

   vendor: Broadcom Corporation

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0

   version: 02

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list

   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0

   resources: irq:17 memory:a0600000-a0603fff
   ```

Thank you, any help is great, I am only 14 and I just need a bit of help.

Also, if this doesn't work, will an older version of Ubuntu or a different Linux work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

It should now be working.

Comment: that didnt work!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please run and post: dmesg | grep b43. The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Comment: i got it to work on ubuntu 12.04 instead of 12.10

Comment: Glad it's working!

Comment: Thanks but it's not that important but my keyboard backlight won't work now

Comment: I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: I did but nobody answered yet http://askubuntu.com/questions/251089/mac-keyboard-backlight-ubuntu-12-04