# Wi-Fi on MacBook Pro 8,1

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, 13.10

[This has been answered before.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248830/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-trouble-macbook-pro) The answers is plug in ethernet and install `linux-firmware-nonfree`. I don't have an ethernet connection. How to install that package?

Answer (score 0):

Download this package and transfer it on a USB key or similar: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/b43.zip Drag and drop the file to the desktop of the MacBook. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp Desktop/b43/* /lib/firmware/b43
```

Reboot and you should be all set.